# Container for a string and int for matching and counting?

Tags: c++, string, compare, int, containers

In C++ what would be the simplest way to create a temporary container to store a string and int like the C# dictionary where I can easily match the string key against another string and increase or decrease the entry value int ?

The content of the container would come from a string where each word separated by a space is an key entry, and all values of each key start with 0.

```
Dictionary<string, int> Options = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Options.Add("xyz", 0);
Options.Add("abc", 0);
Options.Add("dfg", 0);
```

Then I have to compare it against the user option, something like:

```
if (Options.ContainsKey(user_opt))
    Options[user_opt]++;
```

I was initially trying something with vectors **but since my knowledge with C++ is barely 0 I am mostly stuck'ed at it.**

With vectors this is what I got:

```
vector<string> Options;
boost::split(Options, m_StartMode, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to store key, value.

```
std::map<std::string, int> Options;
Options.insert(std::make_pair("xyz", 0));
Options.insert(std::make_pair("abc", 1));
```

Then use `map::find` to check if key exists:

```
std::map<std::string,int>::iterator iter;
iter = Options.find(user_opt);

if(iter != Options.end())
   iter->second++;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time that does the work just fine, is there a simple way to verify which Key has the biggest value as well and return the key name ?

Comment: For that you have to write your own code. You may use `std::max_element` function, but you need to write your own functor.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/).

Comment: Hi, I understand that this might be too much to ask but would it be possible for you to show me an example based on what I am trying to workout ?